# pyglet drawing primitive GL_POINT. A buffer issue?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Beginner in pyglet. I have an issue when drawing `GL_POINT` using `pyglet.graphicss.draw()`. I want this `GL_POINT` to be drawn after another on the next pixel buffer, but it seems the function does not keep the last `GL_POINT` to be drawn on the next pixel buffer.

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import key  # for key input, on_key_press

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)  # create a window object with the resolution of 800x600
window.set_caption('window title')
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):  # keyboard input handler
    if symbol == key.L: # Drawing a center point
        print("DRAWING TEST A POINT (400, 300)")
        pyglet.graphics.draw(
            1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
            ('v2i', (400, 300))
        )

    elif symbol == key.K: # Drawing a bit further 100 more horizontally from center point
        print("DRAWING TEST A POINT (500, 300)")
        pyglet.graphics.draw(
            1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
            ('v2i', (500, 300))
        )

pyglet.app.run()
```

Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> would draw a center point.

[image]

Then pressing <kbd>K</kbd> would draw 100 more horizontally from the center point with the last center point gone.

[image]

Where is the bug? is there something wrong with my code? if not,
my guess would be, does `pyglet.graphicss.draw()` function actually redraw one after another primitive shape? How do I code to draw one after another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by [Double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics). You can solve the issue by drawing the point to both buffers. Draw the point twice and swap the OpenGL front and back buffers in between by ([`flip`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/window.html)).

```py
pyglet.graphics.draw(
    1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', (400, 300))
)
window.flip()
pyglet.graphics.draw(
    1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
    ('v2i', (400, 300))
)
```

But I recommend to add the points to a list and to draw the list. e.g.:

```py
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import key  # for key input, on_key_press

points = []

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)  # create a window object with the resolution of 800x600
window.set_caption('window title')
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):  # keyboard input handler
    global points
    if symbol == key.L: # Drawing a center point
        print("DRAWING TEST A POINT (400, 300)")
        points += [400, 300]

    elif symbol == key.K: # Drawing a bit further 100 more horizontally from center point
        print("DRAWING TEST A POINT (500, 300)")
        points += [500, 300]

    pyglet.graphics.draw(len(points) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS, ('v2i', points))

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: THANK YOU! you helped me out figured it out. But after considering more, I'll go with your recommendation.

Also, this would be out of topic, the method with `window.flip()` is actually having a delayed drawing (like a blinking blank screen) when redrawing, is it because of the  performance or the draw function?

Comment: @NabilAsykar It's because of `window.flip()`. Window flip has to do a complete OpenGL flush. That was just for explanation, you should not do it at all.